# Color transform bitmap in mouse area

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am currently doing a project where I need to change bitmap data to transparent based on mouse movement.  I have managed to use the below to get the effect I want but it shows up as a rectangle and was hoping to find a solution to do a circle.

```
var adjustAlpha:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
adjustAlpha.alphaMultiplier = 0;
var clearArea:Rectangle = new Rectangle(mybitmap.mouseX,mybitmap.mouseY,100,100);
mybitmap.bitmapData.colorTransform(clearArea, adjustAlpha);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're going completely transparent, why not just make a circular mask from a circular MovieClip and see through your bitmap in that way?

There's no direct way to do a negative, or inverse, mask in Flash but read here:

http://franto.com/inverse-masking-disclosed/

for an indirect way.